# MobileFirst 7.1 and Android SDK 23

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I would like to know if MobileFirst 7.1 is compatible with Android SDK 23. My current application is build on SDK 21. What are the pros and cons of moving to 23 with MFP 7.1?

Answer (score 1):

The support is currently lacking. There is an open APAR to fix this. Once the support for API level 23 is added it will be available through an iFix from IBM Fix Central.

Comment: What do you mean by support is lacking? Can you please provide some more details. Are there any list of feature that are impacted?

Comment: There are some incompatibilities preventing MFP apps to run on devices running an OS that supports API level 23.

Comment: Does that means our App which is build on SDK 21 will not run on Android Marshmallow (SDK 23)?

Comment: It might not. Please open a PMR if you require additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check this - 
[Android 6.0 Marshmallow support in IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21966679&aid=1)